# on a summer morning or in a summer morning?

Tags: prepositions

I just read

> If you go there on a summer morning...

I wonder why it says "*on a summer morning*", if the preposition for "summer" and "morning" is "in". It's "*in the summer*" and "*in the morning*".

Unless they are making "*on a summer morning*" equal to "*on a Sunday*".

Answer (score 1):

The *only* context I can think of where we use *in* with *morning* is the single phrase *in the morning*, which can mean "tomorrow morning", or "the morning of the next day", or a habitual "on a typical morning", or it can qualify a further expression of time ("three weeks from now, in the morning").

In all other contexts we either use no preposition ("I saw him yesterday morning") or use "on".

The iWeb corpus confirms this: *in the morning* gets 320,615 hits, while all other *in * morning* together get around 11 thousand hits, but by inspection almost all of these are different constructions: either with *in* as an adverb or particle on the end of the previous phrase (eg "they came in this morning"), or with *morning* used attributely with a following noun phrase (eg "we see in our morning papers that ...").

The same applies to *evening* and *afternoon*: we can say *in the evening*, *in the afternoon*, but in any other context, if there is a preposition it is *on*.

Comment: I started online bitcoin trading at 8 AM. I was sure I had found a sure-fire site. But it was a scam. Shortly before noon I had no money left. My life savings were gone in a morning.

Comment: Trust @MichaelHarvey to find a counterexample to anything I claim! Yes, _in a morning (afternoon, evening, hour, day)_ can be used in the sense of "within the interval of a morning etc".